# img не хочет выравниваться по центру

Tags: html, css

Блок с картинкой никак не хочет выравниваться. Пробовал через margin, vertical-align. задавал разные display и ему и родителям. Может я слепой и что-то упускаю?

```css
.mob_img_width {
  display: block;
  width: 282px;
  max-height: 282px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.tovar p.foto a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.tovar p.foto {
  height: 282px!important;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.tovar {
  width: 30% !important;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="fl">
  <div class="tovar">
    <p class="foto">
      <a href="/product/4087/Nakatka_START"><img class="mob_img_select" id="photo_4087" src="/files/products/thumbs105/07620.png" alt="" /></a>
    </p>
    <p class="text"><a href="/product/4087/Nakatka_START">Накатка START</a></p>
    <p class="info">
      <span class="chena"><b>41 630</b> руб.</span>
      <span class="buy"><a class="addtocart btn_green" href="/orders/toCart/4087">Купить</a></span>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

Comment: @МузыкаСергей Сработало, но вопрос, а почему не хотел работать метод через vertical:align или margin?

Comment: @АртемАртем, так вы по вертикали или по горизонтали хотели выровнять?

Comment: @АртемАртем увы но был оффлайн 2 дня, вот хорошая статья по vertical-align: https://web-standards.ru/articles/vertical-align/

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб через margin выравнивать - картинка должна быть блоком.

Comment: ну так я ему дисплей блок ставил же, или это не помогает?)

Comment: Так у тебя вроде у ссылки блок а не у картинки)
В твоем случае text-align: center для ссылки выведет картинку на центр как вариант)